# The map $H_0(S^n) \to H_0(E_-^n)$ is surjective

Tags: algebraic-topology, homological-algebra, homotopy-theory

Let $E_-^n := \{(x_1,\ldots,x_{n+1}) \in S^n \mid x_{n+1} \le 0\}$ be defining the lower hemisphere and $x \in E_-^n$.

I try to understand why we have that the map of homology group $H_0(S^n) \to H_0(E_-^n)$ is surjective. The reason is given as follow:

We observe the following diagramm:
[image]
Taking now the homology, we get:
[image]
Now since $E_-^n$ is contractible, we know that $H_0(x) \to H(E_-^n)$ is an isomorphisms. We have from the axiom, that $H_0(x)=R$. So the map $H_0(S^n) \to H_0(E_-^n)$ must be surjective... I don't understand why this should be true... How can we conclude that?

Many thanks for your help!

Comment: If $h = f\circ g$ and $h$ is onto, then $f$ should also be onto.

Comment: This would mean, that we have a commutative diagram, no? Is it here the case?

Comment: Yes, the commutativity is by functoriality of $H_0$. But I don't know why you would do it so complicatedly: You don't need that $E^n_-$ is contractible, only that it is path-connected.

Comment: This is proved in my answer to your question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4354189/the-map-h-0sn-to-h-0e-n-is-surjective. Since $c_* i_*$ is the identity, $c_*$ must be surjective.

Comment: So to understand right, the first diagramm is commutative, so the seconde one too and hence we have that it must be surjective?

Comment: You can see it that way, yes.